# AngularJS, calculation addition (+) is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I tried to calculate $scope values through angular controller. For instance: the below code works in order to multiply values inside brackets. However, addition(+) is working like 400+200 = 400200. How to get output 600?

```
   $scope.output = ($scope.quantity.Quantity * $scope.pro_price) + $scope.wait_price;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the variable, since your scope variable might be of type string,

```
$scope.output = ($scope.quantity.Quantity * $scope.pro_price) + parseInt($scope.wait_price);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/yT3h7a4tJzWyBZdJrRNL?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks machan. I expected you here. How can I tag you on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
 $scope.output = ($scope.quantity.Quantity * $scope.pro_price) - ( -1 * $scope.wait_price);
```

Comment: That is because it take + as a concat operation , so use - like above, I think overhead is less.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Unary Plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to get the summation correct.

Here is what you could do.

```
$scope.output = ($scope.quantity.Quantity * $scope.pro_price) + (+$scope.wait_price);
```

A working example of this explanation is here.

```js
var valueOne = 1;
var valueTwo = "20";

console.log("Regular + operator", (valueOne + valueTwo));

console.log("Unary + operator", (valueOne + (+valueTwo)));
```